# Android - Can we change keysize of existing signing keystore

Tags: keystore, android-keystore, android-signing

Can we change keysize of existing keystore(.keystore) that is used for signing existing app? I want to change it from 1024 to 2048.

If it is not possible then what can be the work-around so that it does not break the app update of existing app.

PS: Don't have any details on how the existing keystore was generated.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately could not find any

Comment: Starting with APK signature scheme v2 an APK file can have multiple signatures. This way you can sign your APK files by both the old and the new key. So you have in the end both: the new key plus a working update mechanism.

Comment: @RS_Mob Any solution